# Another user should be able to update the protected range in google spreadsheet using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, google-sheets, web-deployment, google-sheets-api

I have shared a sheet with protected range with another user and wants them to submit data such as the invoice copy or data from a specific range of cells of one sheet to another, using a **SUBMIT** button to which the respective script is assigned.

Scenario:
Two spreadsheets namely S1 and S2, of which S2 is protected and another user wants to submit data from S1 to S2 after he/she presses the submit button.

```
function testing() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('S1');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('S2');

  s1.getRange("A1:G1").copyTo(s2.getRange("A1:G1"));
  }
```

Also, I have read that this can be done by deploying the script as the web app. I tried that by going into "Deploy as web app" and setting the script to run as admin(me) and accessible to anonymous. But still no positive result.

Did put something like this for web app deployment:

```
function doGet(e){
  return testing(e);
}

function testing() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('S1');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('S2');

  s1.getRange("A1:G1").copyTo(s2.getRange("A1:G1"));
}
```

> > Error Says:
> >     You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.

Can someone walk me through the process or tell me where I am going wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the code like that you are calling the `testing()` function as is using whatever account and permissions the current user has.

What you need to do is use the `UrlFetchApp` to call the `doGet()` this will run the script as the user who published the app:

1: Copy and paste the code

```
function copyRange() {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("--- Copy this URL from step 3 ---");
}

function doGet(e) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

    s1.getRange("A1").copyTo(s2.getRange("A1"));

}
```

2: Click 'Publish' - 'Deploy' set new project version to execute as Me and allow anyone as you did in your test. Click 'Update'

3: Copy the Current web app URL and paste it into the `fetch()` save the script.

Now any user should be able to run the function or going to the URL from step 3 will trigger the function.

Comment: Hey, another addition to above question:

I am trying to use : 

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

but then it runs the script without generating any ui as needed. Error says : "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context". 
Is it something that doGet() can't generate or access getUi() ?